# Why does it take so long between focusout and click on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jquery-events

I am trying to make my own combobox and I have problems with `focusout` timings thus I have set up a simple example to see the problem:

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FkLbH/1/)**

which basically has two events on two items:

```
$('#iii').focusout(function (e)
{
    write('focusout');
});

$('#ddd').click(function (e)
{
    write('click');
});
```

When I click to edit the input `iii` and the click on the div `ddd` it takes like 95 milliseconds or so.

Indirectly related stuff: Once I have some of my own logic in `click` event, this time ads up to even higher numbers, making it look bad visually. That `ddd` represents the choices of my combobox and the input is for filtering out the items.

When I focus on the input I open the `ddd` for the user to pick choices.

When I focus out the input the `ddd` closes.

When I click on a certain choice in `ddd` I want the `ddd` to stay.

Thus I add a `setTimeout` in focus out and use a flag to indicate whether the user clicks inside `ddd` and if yes, I do let it stay open and `focusin` again.

**My question is: why does it take so long going from one event to another?** Optional question: maybe I can do something better with my combobox (you can find the more sophisticated idea of what I am stuck with in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LJcQe/6/))